# Showing only hovered image on absolutely positioned elements/images?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an issue when hovering outfits (images) on page that has class `explore-outfit`. They are **absolutely** positioned and can sometimes overlap eachother. When hovering these images a popup is shown according that relates to the product. (*Yes I know I can use data-attribute instead of this messy way to retreive ID but nevermind that for the moment*)

I have this **jQuery:**

```
$('#outfit-area-public').on('mouseover', '.explore-outfit', function(e) {  
        //Get id of clicked image
        var idArray = $(this).attr("id").split("prodimage_");   
        //array of split between _id, example: [0] = prod, [1] = 287
        var newId = idArray[1]; 
        var showDetails = '#prod_' + newId;

        //Show div with id prod_{id}            
        $(".details-info").hide();        
        $(showDetails).show(1000); //showDetails element has class details-info
    });
```

The issue is that `$(".details-info").hide();` doesn't always hide every popup (with class details-info) before showing current hovered outfit (so 2 popups for outfits are shown at the same time).

I've tried with hide() callback but this doesn't work either: What am I missing?

```
$( ".details-info").hide( "fast", function() {
            $(showDetails).show();
});
```

Comment: Please reproduce you problem in a code snippet...

Answer (score 0):

If someone stumbles upon similar issue this is my solution (by check value of global variable when hidden or not hidden). Sometimes it helps to just create question here to actually figure out how to solve things.

```
var showingPoup = false;

$('#outfit-area-public').on('mouseover', '.explore-outfit', function(e) {  
            if (showingPopup === false) {
                //Get id of clicked image
                var idArray = $(this).attr("id").split("prodimage_");   
                //array of split between _id, example: [0] = prod, [1] = 287
                var newId = idArray[1]; 
                var showDetails = '#prod_' + newId;

                //Show div with id prod_{id}                      
                showingPopup = true;
                $(".details-info").hide();                    
                $( showDetails ).show( 500, function() {
                       showingPopup = false;        
                });
            }

    });
```